# Data Attribute on a Model Class not get posted in Web Api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-web-api

I have written following code to post JSon data to Web Api Class

```
var product = '{Id: 2012, Name: 'test', Category: 'My Category', Price: 99.5}'

$.ajax({
url: 'api/products',
type: 'POST',
data: JSON.stringify(product),
dataType: 'json',
contentType: "application/json",
success: function (data) {
}
});
```

On Server side i have defined a Post Method with following code

```
  public HttpResponseMessage Post(Product p)
    {
       //some code to manipulate p and return response 
       return response;
    }
```

The Product is Model class containing Id, Name, Category and Price attribute.

Problem :- When in Model class i add attribute of Required on Id, Name and other properties, data does not get posted and Server return 500 Error with a message ID is Required?

What could be the possible reason of problem or in other words how to post Json data for a model having properties with Attributes.

Comment: Keep in mind that if any attribute on your model class is labeled as private it won't be loaded.

Answer (score 1):

You're double-stringifying the product data, and you shouldn't be stringifying it at all; JQuery's [`ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method takes a JSON object for data.

```
var product = {Id: 2012, Name: 'test', Category: 'My Category', Price: 99.5};

$.ajax({
    url: 'api/products',
    type: 'POST',
    data: product,
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (data) {
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a better practice to decorate the serverside method which is accepting jquery post with a HttpPost attribute.

```
[HttpPost]
  public HttpResponseMessage Post(Product p)
{
   //some code to manipulate p and return response 
   return response;
}
```

and follow the same as per dbaseman